# Ethernet IP-Address 169

Tags: windows, networking, lan, dhcp

I have bought this new laptop and the LAN is just not working. It has no default gateway and the IPv4 address is 169.xx.xx.xx. It can detect that there is a LAN cable connected, but it says the network does not have a valid IP-Address. It is not a router problem, as it does not work at my school either.

Things I have already tried:

> 1. ipconfig /release
> 2. ipconfig /renew
> 3. Reinstalling the driver multiple times
> 4. Deleting the driver and restarting making windows install it itself.
> 5. Update BIOS
> 6. Disabling IPv6
> 7. Typing IP-Address manually
> 8. Starting windows in safe mode
> 9. I tried to stop DHCP server but I get access denied. The DHCP server says "running".
> 10. I even tried a completely new Harddisk, same problem.

What I think could be the problem:

> 1. I tried to ping 127.0.0.0 and it was successful in doing so with 0% loss.
> 2. When I tried to do ipconfig /renew I get the following message:
>
> "An error occured while renewing interface Local Area Connection : unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out."

So that makes me think that it has something to do with my DHCP server. But I have no idea what to do. WiFi on the laptop works wihtout a problem.

Here is a print of my ipconfig /all to a text file:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Jens
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter LAN-forbindelse* 22:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : CA-3D-D4-91-73-AD
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C8-5B-76-F9-9A-A2
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9dff:6d8f:d759:b195%15(Preferred) 
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.177.149(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 264788854
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-BE-EE-66-C8-3D-D4-91-73-AD
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek 8821AE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C8-3D-D4-91-73-AD
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::fdbb:37f2:b8d8:df44%30(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.108(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 10. december 2017 15:02:18
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 10. december 2017 17:22:40
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 566771156
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-BE-EE-66-C8-3D-D4-91-73-AD
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth-netv‘rksforbindelse 5:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C8-3D-D4-91-73-AE
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: You seem to have properly covered most of your bases here, assuming you did all your testing correctly on multiple known networks (as it appears), this sure sounds like defective hardware. The other thing I would try is loading up a live Linux distribution and see if you can duplicate the issue. Otherwise, I would consider contacting the vendor/seller for replacement.

Comment: The output of ipconfig doesn’t match your information.  192.168.x.x does t match 169.x.x.x however 169 subnet means you have no DHCP: https://superuser.com/questions/482520/why-am-i-getting-a-169-ip-address-at-startup so you have to determine the reason your DHCP isn’t working

Comment: @Ramhound Look at the question again, the WiFi adapter with a 192 address is working, the Ethernet adapter has a 169 address. The asker also stated they tried it at school as well which I assumed meant it didn't work at "home" or somewhere else, and they tried a static IP address, yet the network adapter shows a link present, assuming the testing was done correctly. Although I am making some assumptions here, I have to think this is more than just the DHCP server isn't responding to the request. I wonder if connecting another device to the same port yield usable IP information.

Comment: 168.x.x.x is assigned when DHCP services are not working.  It’s either the service itself on the pc or the server itself.  Problem with including to much information is users on phones miss scrolling down a quote block fully

Answer (score 3):

You need to determine whether your router - where your LAN cable ends - does or does not supply DHCP. If it does not, then the behaviour you're observing (an address in the [link-local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) APIPA range of 169.254.*.*) is **perfectly normal** and you need to configure a static IP address, not a dynamic one.

If it does, chances are this is a hardware problem (might be something as silly as a bent pin or speck of dirt in the RJ45 socket; or something equally silly, but difficult to fix without voiding the warranty, as a badly soldered pad on the motherboard's side of the RJ45 connector).

You can ask at your school what their network configuration is. Unfortunately, chances are that it is DHCP based, so your laptop not working is a bad sign.

However, it's not automatically the hardware; you also want to check the status of your DHCP *client* on the laptop. You wrote,

> I tried to stop DHCP server but I get access denied. The DHCP server says "running".

but it is the DHCP **client** that should be running on your laptop; the DHCP server assigns addresses, it does not - as far as I know - request them for allocation.

Answer (score 3):

The IP address 169.x.x.x is one that the computer allocates to itself when it is unable to receive an IP address from the DHCP server.

This could be for any number of reasons:

- The DHCP client software on your computer is not running properly and not processing sending the DHCP request or processing the DHCP response from the router.
- There could be a break in the connection to the router.
- There could be some kind of ethernet configuration setting that is not correct. E.g. the network might require an 802.1X certificate or login which might not be present, etc.  The network might have blacklisted your MAC address preventing communication.

This is all speculation.  One way to get more information about what is happening is to use a packet capture tool such as WireShark.  Then you can see the traffic and whether your computer is responding correctly.

You could also try booting up another operating system (e.g. using a linux boot disk) to rule out any operating system issues on your side - if it works then it is an operating system issue.  If not, then it is likely a network issue.

Interestingly, your screen shows that your WiFi connection appears to be up and has an IP address.  The ethernet connection shows DHCP servers with IPv6 addresses.  Perhaps your network is using only IPv6, which might not work if that is not turned on on your ethernet interface.